# Facebook Redirect Query

Tags: javascript, python, html, facebook

This is a followup to a previous question I asked.  I have the URL encoded in a Facebook ad, and I want my python program to get the end URL that it redirects to using javascript.  Because it uses javascript, the normal urllib2/mechanize ways of tracking redirects don't work, and I'm a little lost as to what my next step should be in tackling this problem as I'm fairly new to python.

The HTML from the original URL (which redirects when placed in a normal browser) is as follows:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */document.location.replace("http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ajax\/emu\/r.php?u=AQIp41Zwc9sY8Ww3nVilFEp65wGTqRy0HFkoPknfO0PMmv8ReqE5hUWspFXZpc5voUSBpsALvKAELk_nKIxnbfo3exlOLjD6e37JqMqTu8_mhtsdYHW1D2TBW9ja5tz8RevsT2C6ioKSVImbTA1aCAvZfSOum2_utZe-FQZQy7hUJvIxgwUlgxCBO00MyFnChMBk3srXc3FlZZWGJh5bLXtX0PlCaGfNwzsS1pHBsI_aEZeuWvrqh2x264WxQloG15QKkYg7zfvyoOTByNRR686THDx9KyV52eRAkME3z2pM76sYr0NjOkBXJaMQuc0qvVuz5OF3mhaPGW3cjcCh9K2j_he7GC-cyDtcdMevIT0qSH4sxCM9KxqnsRPTIHBAXEDPQysAdadyfs3p3Q3rgg1atUzGzdkCshyqaoDhHFhBreUYJ2TUWm7DQ7cpJ9vYDQ2qEvaZxUiz67RKzmIPqi7Zzidzo6t19yMwGGSIcdxg87xZZ5qZ8NGV8VdXXvQ-AxA-xOt4fiWJmVJUnaAl8m46ATo0K3prACIJN8FILMBYPWlDW7tmOGIvcT8CA-lwXysrVvkZjMJxhzknmw0hZ8gt9E1RVmeCNKb8xmGp1acXGsy49OZlXqk0wiLIFY04gCs8vo3FmHHEGQUX4ZECeFCbAdVUBDzHwRPyMtwVZ4dVoBwws6oiXVtAYDe4KCVGRQe_-axOVxO_zhWH8J4q89E_hWVJ0_dlhkhSotyzeh3flKXfzgKr8VDs07ZIl8v9XTvIZD2PRUxmBT9IRxzCUv9UC0s4JMG7-TnKoANh133TrwpiDx-QWT_9rRAoM4oupazJxy4tkudUICCG3ancGpGdP_GcWAGkRlc5p25kBi4eiqJgO-KIxNVg5YkEINh5NlblQY16pGbqtkOmYmxQedahuPkykAexOsYtuaZRv4k3DGjLR-uBUhHkpUz0SS3fJwbVcuCgq5Aup27-bjR9bgFnHDMLWF0EbNBHB_0d0oppzAh93x7yVCvt-acoNS9KBSKNNnRUn3H0ZsDd0HBOT-oI_aZKfiumD2NYjgwXJWRPb54_85ju89ZeD9KUBwCqfPFc0Wr6TOtAUxrv-7nr_Bn3MUkGI5zWmnA32QOMHzay1CtLZ5FRzcwXEXIVfrJeeVvm3x-4TCxQ4FrCa591VAj3B_hCYdv6IzERGkBm6K3LKd1EZL_dATRRegKjNavUChzI2_rLAyrMduLniaD7H1bwktNq78GXAT3taId-FVysw8Il7OamCKldlWtbcuGL2KHfNHVBWigi2AuqdyagRPmIqLcIe7TkdiZ4e9n5bm9O_M9MuX0OV0NseOMbmUFvQMZSAjXE_hrwJjanlHVUdNiL5psdujE_RVM4uwNhb9t-VhCJw70HhUG-Xqc0O09cfemJfGnoFRRPmFkTuX_dg1Fzx_ARCBnl6GBjbMdiLle3eduaK7ldN1VU9BstZjKNqWn691qxaJGdzCVaYo3w_5SMQfC9OfceWtrMQ-UZ3cnfG2lJ_w6yEDa-1b6rZ9UQRnA");/* ]]> */</script><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */setTimeout("(new Image()).src='/laudit.php?r=JS&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Femu%2Fr.php%3Fu%3DAQIp41Zwc9sY8Ww3nVilFEp65wGTqRy0HFkoPknfO0PMmv8ReqE5hUWspFXZpc5voUSBpsALvKAELk_nKIxnbfo3exlOLjD6e37JqMqTu8_mhtsdYHW1D2TBW9ja5tz8RevsT2C6ioKSVImbTA1aCAvZfSOum2_utZe-FQZQy7hUJvIxgwUlgxCBO00MyFnChMBk3srXc3FlZZWGJh5bLXtX0PlCaGfNwzsS1pHBsI_aEZeuWvrqh2x264WxQloG15QKkYg7zfvyoOTByNRR686THDx9KyV52eRAkME3z2pM76sYr0NjOkBXJaMQuc0qvVuz5OF3mhaPGW3cjcCh9K2j_he7GC-cyDtcdMevIT0qSH4sxCM9KxqnsRPTIHBAXEDPQysAdadyfs3p3Q3rgg1atUzGzdkCshyqaoDhHFhBreUYJ2TUWm7DQ7cpJ9vYDQ2qEvaZxUiz67RKzmIPqi7Zzidzo6t19yMwGGSIcdxg87xZZ5qZ8NGV8VdXXvQ-AxA-xOt4fiWJmVJUnaAl8m46ATo0K3prACIJN8FILMBYPWlDW7tmOGIvcT8CA-lwXysrVvkZjMJxhzknmw0hZ8gt9E1RVmeCNKb8xmGp1acXGsy49OZlXqk0wiLIFY04gCs8vo3FmHHEGQUX4ZECeFCbAdVUBDzHwRPyMtwVZ4dVoBwws6oiXVtAYDe4KCVGRQe_-axOVxO_zhWH8J4q89E_hWVJ0_dlhkhSotyzeh3flKXfzgKr8VDs07ZIl8v9XTvIZD2PRUxmBT9IRxzCUv9UC0s4JMG7-TnKoANh133TrwpiDx-QWT_9rRAoM4oupazJxy4tkudUICCG3ancGpGdP_GcWAGkRlc5p25kBi4eiqJgO-KIxNVg5YkEINh5NlblQY16pGbqtkOmYmxQedahuPkykAexOsYtuaZRv4k3DGjLR-uBUhHkpUz0SS3fJwbVcuCgq5Aup27-bjR9bgFnHDMLWF0EbNBHB_0d0oppzAh93x7yVCvt-acoNS9KBSKNNnRUn3H0ZsDd0HBOT-oI_aZKfiumD2NYjgwXJWRPb54_85ju89ZeD9KUBwCqfPFc0Wr6TOtAUxrv-7nr_Bn3MUkGI5zWmnA32QOMHzay1CtLZ5FRzcwXEXIVfrJeeVvm3x-4TCxQ4FrCa591VAj3B_hCYdv6IzERGkBm6K3LKd1EZL_dATRRegKjNavUChzI2_rLAyrMduLniaD7H1bwktNq78GXAT3taId-FVysw8Il7OamCKldlWtbcuGL2KHfNHVBWigi2AuqdyagRPmIqLcIe7TkdiZ4e9n5bm9O_M9MuX0OV0NseOMbmUFvQMZSAjXE_hrwJjanlHVUdNiL5psdujE_RVM4uwNhb9t-VhCJw70HhUG-Xqc0O09cfemJfGnoFRRPmFkTuX_dg1Fzx_ARCBnl6GBjbMdiLle3eduaK7ldN1VU9BstZjKNqWn691qxaJGdzCVaYo3w_5SMQfC9OfceWtrMQ-UZ3cnfG2lJ_w6yEDa-1b6rZ9UQRnA';",5000);/* ]]> */</script></body></html>
```

I'm sorry for the way I posted that, but my question is, is the redirect link somewhere here?  I've tried a bunch of different ways to copy the things that look like links in the HTML, but have had no luck.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[`document.location.replace()`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0320__Location/Locationreplace.htm) is how you perform a redirect using JavaScript. If you parse out the URL within that method call, then you could follow that URL manually within your code.

Comment: Ah, yeah.  That's what I thought, but when I copy the link out of the document.location.replace() and put it in my browser after removing/modifying the "\"s, I get a "Page Not Found" from Facebook.  But I know this javascript works!

Comment: Yeah this is a crappy move on Facebook's part. They're breaking the Internet by not using the HTTP protocol correctly.